# Функция автогенерации поля в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql9.6

Недавно столкнулся с необходимостью автогенерации значений в ячейке таблицы по умолчанию.

***Задача следующая:***
Есть два поля **pepl_id**, в котором хранится идентификатор пользователя, и **pepl_login**, в котором должен быть уникальный Логин, но если он не указывается, то логин должен формироваться автоматически по принципу *'Какое-то слово'* + **pepl_id**. Например, имеется *клиент с ID 123*, слово будет *'Login'* (как ни странно). Функция должна вернуть *Login123*.

Есть также аналогичная задача, но из той же оперы. Нужна функция, которая будет возвращать **КОД** пользователя по принципу *1 буква фамилии* + *буква 'П'* + *id пользователя*. Например, для *пользователя Иванов с id 123* будет **КОД** *ИП123*.

Как это можно реализовать в PostgreSQL? Если будут можете, приведите пример с PgAdmin. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Используйте триггеры, тут есть даже нужный вам пример: http://postgresql.ru.net/docs/trigger.html

Comment: @AlexKrass, спасибо большое, сейчас посмотрю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой благодаря @AlexKrass.
Вот код к моему первому примеру про Логины:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_pepl_before () 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN 
NEW.pepl_login=COALESCE(NEW.pepl_login,'User'||NEW.pepl_id);
return NEW;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER people_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON people FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_pepl_before ();
```

В данном случае создается триггерная функция, которая используется вызывается триггером.
Переменная NEW хранит данные добавляемой строки. А функция COALESCE([...]) возвращает первый элемент, который не равен null.
Таким образом, мы пишем в этой строке `NEW.pepl_login=COALESCE(NEW.pepl_login,'User'||NEW.pepl_id);`, если pepl_login равен null, то использовать значение 'User'+id, создаваемого пользователя и передаем в качестве нового логина, если не равен null, то передаем тоже значение, что и было. В конце просто возвращаем обновленный NEW, в качестве добавляемой строки.

Не знаю зачем я пытаюсь разжевать, вроде и так понятно ^^ Может кому-то будет полезно.